# Binding ASP.NET listview to DataTable variable

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am binding a listview to datatable variable. My idea is to modify the DataTable upon Delete, Insert, Update Requests from ListView, and save it to Database only when user wants. But, after postback, my DataTable becomes null. Is there any way to resolve it? Is this right way to bind a ListView without connecting Database ?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!Page.IsPostBack){
          DataTable DTReceipts = new DataTable("DTReceipts"); 
          DTReceipts.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
          new DataColumn("ExpenseReceiptID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
          new DataColumn("TransactionSeqNumber", Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
          new DataColumn("TransactionSeqSub", Type.GetType("System.String")),
          new DataColumn("TransactionDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime")),
          new DataColumn("ReceiptNumber", Type.GetType("System.String")),
          new DataColumn("Vendor_EntityID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
          new DataColumn("Description", Type.GetType("System.String")),
          new DataColumn("SubProjectID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
          new DataColumn("AllocationID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
          new DataColumn("AllocationScope", Type.GetType("System.String")),
          new DataColumn("DeductFromVendor_EntityID", Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
          new DataColumn("DeductionAmount", Type.GetType("System.Double")),
          new DataColumn("EmployeeID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
         });
         for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
         {
          DataRow drr = DTReceipts.NewRow();
          drr["ExpenseReceiptID"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["TransactionSeqNumber"] = i.ToString();
          drr["TransactionSeqSub"] = "";
          drr["TransactionDate"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["ReceiptNumber"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["Vendor_EntityID"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["Description"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["SubProjectID"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["AllocationID"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["AllocationScope"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["DeductFromVendor_EntityID"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["DeductionAmount"] = DBNull.Value;
          drr["EmployeeID"] = DBNull.Value;
          DTReceipts.Rows.Add(drr);
         }
         ExpenseReceiptsList.DataSource = DTReceipts;
         ExpenseReceiptsList.DataBind(); 
     }
   }
```

Comment: You need to store the `DataTable` somewhere so that is can be restored in the post back. You can perhaps store it in the `Session`, or even in `ViewState`. But I'd suggest you go ahead and actually store each row directly to the database, then have some kind of header record with a flag that signals that the report/transaction/work flow is complete.

Comment: Thanks @user1429080 I also feel database connection is much better.